# What is the correct way of declaring a function taking a generic IEnumerable as argument?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a method which takes an `IEnumerable<T>` as arguement but the compiler gives me error.

Here is the method signature -

```
public void Bind<IEnumerable<T>>(IEnumerable<T> instance)
{

}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have done no research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing special about `IEnumerable`, you've just got the syntax slightly wrong.

Change your code as:

```
public void Bind<T>(IEnumerable<T> instance)
{
     ...
}
```